# Should var be used when variable is already a parameter (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have a function like so

```
function foo(x){
    if (typeof x === 'undefined'){
        var x = 123;
    }
}
```

is the `var` statement necessary? JSlint complains that `variable x hides argument` (probably b/c I am defining a variable in the scope of the if statement.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `vim`.

Comment: jsLint complains because you are inface hiding the argument. In other words if you were to use `x` again in that if statement you would be referencing the variable containing `123` not whatever the parameter was. If you are trying to reasign the arguments value, just do `x = 123`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `var` is not necessary, and in fact it is a mistake. You should use `var` to declare a new variable. Once the function has an argument `x` it is declared - whether it is passed a value or not.

By the way, in such cases when you know the variable is declared but just don't know whether it's been assigned a value or not, you can write `x === undefined` - using `typeof` and a string comparison is not necessary.

Comment: what if it's not declared? I'm always worried about `undefined` because being `undefined` an being set to `undefined` generate two different things.

Comment: If you're not sure the variable is declared use `typeof` and compare to `"undefined"`, as `x === undefined` generates an error when `x` is not declared. (But if you're sure `x` is declared, just not sure whether it was assigned a value or not, then `x === undefined` is good enough [and even better].)

Comment: To be honest with you, 99% of the time I use this functionality to check to see if an object has a property or not. Even the majority of my arguments I pass around as objects. And with those you never know if something is declared.

Comment: If it's a property of an object you also don't have to use `typeof`. (And if it's a global variable, you can treat it as a property of `window`: `window.foo === undefined`.)

Comment: Woa! Good coding practices 101. Basically use `window.global` notation for all globals, which lets you use `===undefined`. Variables and arguments are compliant too. When would you use `typeof`?

Comment: When I want to check something's type? :)

Comment: Tom, I guess I could understand it being used in a switch statement, otherwise, wouldn't you just use `===`

Comment: For `undefined` I generally use `===`. But you can use `typeof` to check other types as well. (Notice that something of type `"undefined"` has always got the value `undefined`, but of course things of other types may have all kinds of values - so for other types you need `typeof` - comparing to a specific value is not enough.)

Comment: javascript really is a language which takes time to master

Answer (score 4):

No `var` is not needed here and it's in fact very misleading.  The `var` modifier is used to scope a value to the current function scope.  Hence it's most useful at the top of the method or at worst on the first usage of the value.  Parameters are always scoped to the current function hence it has no value.

Using it for subsequent usages *suggests* it's the first use / declaration of the value.  This can be misleading to future developers.